# Exclude from wordpress rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Attempting to exclude a folder 'test' from the wordpress rewrite rules in the htaccess file and give it a unique rewrite.  Test isn't a real folder.

So this: `/test/post1/` or this `/test/post1` should rewrite to `/index.php?pagename=$1` where $1 is the posttitle e.g. post1.  I think I have the exclusion working as a `RewriteCond` (see below) - how do I add the `RewriteRule` for it?

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|test/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: test folder inside your wp root folder you need to access that only without wp site ?

Comment: No there is no test folder - it's a query pathway.  `/test/post1/` gets mapped to `/index.php?pagename=$1` if the pathway has `/test/`.

Comment: exclude a folder 'test' from the wordpress rewrite rules in the htaccess,,, this is you mentioned, Can you explain bit brief

Comment: @GNANA I don't understand your comment.

Comment: you mentioned in question " 
exclude a folder 'test' from the wordpress rewrite rules in the htaccess "

Comment: yes and.......?